# meaning of "be overlooked"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Is "overlooked" used properly in the following sentence? If Joe's neighbors live in a higher building than his swimming pool, does the sentence still make sense?

> Joe put a roof over his swimming pool so that it might not be overlooked.

Comment: Technically yes, and you may see this in older texts - in modern practice, no. Usually the word "overlooked" is used to mean "was not noticed" rather than "observe from above".

Other possible ways to word the sentence above:

"Joe put a roof over his swimming pool to maintain privacy." or 
"Joe put a roof over his swimming pool to keep others from watching [some activity]."

Comment: See [definition 2a here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overlook). @entiat I disagree, it's still in common enough use. It's more often used with a subject ("The chateau overlooks the meadow," "the chateau is overlooked by the tower of the neighboring villa") but I've heard the bare adjective version from the question in real estate TV shows. The M-W definition uses a similar example, though by an author who died in 1978, and [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/overlooked) illustrates the same use.

Comment: @AndyBonner I agree that this sense of the verb is still in use, but don't you agree that the writer should probably edit this sentence to avoid the possibility of confusion?

Comment: I agree with Andy Bonner that the word is still in everyday use. The intended meaning is clear enough. Joe didn't roof his pool to get it noticed! _BUT_ it would be more accurate to say, **Joe put a roof over his swimming pool BECAUSE it was overlooked**. Roofing the pool doesn't stop it being overlooked. It just stops people seeing in.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian You've brought up an interesting point which may be embarrassing to lexicographers of Oxford Dictionary, or the online version Lexico. They define "be overlooked" as "(of a place) be open to view and so lack privacy" without reference to relative height of one location to another.

Comment: I wonder if we're getting into subtle differences between dialects of English. I (west coast North America) would never use "be overlooked" to signify "was looked at from above". That context would always mean "was not noticed". For example, "Joe was overlooked in the soup line and did not receive any food." In contrast - and somewhat paradoxically - the example with the chateau overlooking the meadow would indeed be an apt description of real estate, still in wide use (here, at least).

Comment: Just a note that at some point somebody should give an honest to goodness *answer* —but I'm not confident enough about the usages. I will say that @OldBrixtonian, my perception from the usages on home renovation shows is that "overlooked" (with no "by __") *would* be negated by blocking the view. I wish I had a direct quote, but something along the lines of "Let's put in a privacy fence, so our back yard isn't so overlooked."...

Comment: ... @entiat As for regional usages, this *might* have been one of the many such shows filmed in Canada... And as media becomes globalized, I feel like I *might* have also heard it on American-produced shows. I agree that it's a niche usage, restricted mainly to real estate discussions, and that it absolutely should be regarded as unrelated to the "unnoticed" usage.

Comment: Does "Let's put in a privacy fence, so our back yard isn't so overlooked" suggest the fence is extrememly high, as high as the second floor at least?

Comment: This is not an AmE usage -- Canadian I can see. The Love it or List it series is filmed in Canada, so I can see them using it.

Comment: @Apollyon no, not necessarily. Baring viewing from a ground floor window, or simply the neighbouring garden would reduce the amount you're overlooked. Preventing anyone from seeing into your garden from a 1st storey (2nd floor US) windows is further than I've seen this taken.

Comment: @Jontia Do you mean if someone looks into your house from a neighboring garden on ground level, your house is still overlooked, albeit to a lesser extent?

Comment: @Apollyon if someone can see into your house/garden from ground level you are overlooked to a higher extent than if someone can only see in from their 1st floor (US 2nd) window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After all the comments (and learning something!), I'll start an answer. If you are aware of common usage in another locale, please comment and I'll update this answer.*

Answer: **It depends on locale.**

### Britain and (possibly) Canada

The verb **to overlook** is indeed commonly used mean **to observe from above**, as formulated in the original question

> Joe put a roof over his swimming pool so that it might not be overlooked.

### US

The verb **to overlook** almost always means **to fail to notice**. For example

> The detectives overlooked the obvious clues and the murderer escaped.

There are certain exceptions such as the view from a location

> The chateau overlooks the valley.

Thus the sentence from the original question would not be commonly used in the United States. Instead, you find formulations such as

> Joe put a roof over his swimming pool to maintain privacy.

> Joe put a roof over his swimming pool to keep his neighbors from looking in.